# Golang HTML Action By Client

Tags: javascript, html, go, google-translation-api

I am using "Google Translate API" in Golang. I need to have the user select other languages on the HTML page but I could not make connect Golang and JS. in short, I want to change language when clicking language buttons.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/bregydoc/gtranslate"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

type Info struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

var tpl *template.Template
var name string
var lang Info

func main() {
    name = "Hello World"

    translate, err := gtranslate.Translate(name, language.English, language.Spanish)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    name = translate

    fmt.Printf("en: %s | es: %s \n", name, translate)
    // en: Hello World | es: Hola Mundo

    lang = Info{
        Name:name,
    }

    tpl, _ = tpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    http.HandleFunc("/test", hellloHandleFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}
func hellloHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Index Running")
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "form_bootstrap_basic.html", lang)

}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        English
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spanish</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Japanese</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<input id="input-name" type="text" value="{{.Name}}" name="input-name" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Can you add the javascript you are using?

Comment: You can either use some javascript to call the server via Ajax whenever the language is changed, or use a form and submit the form so the handler can translate and rebuild the template.

Comment: `code`$("#spaish-button").on("click", function() {
                $("#input-name").val({{.Name}})
            }) @RuiCosta  I couldn't get too good in javascript code

Comment: If you are trying to translate the text input, then you have to send that data either using Ajax or using a POST form (via a submit button), so the server side can run the translation, and return the result. On the server side, you have to move the translation code into the handler.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your support. I will try your recommendations and share them again. @BurakSerdar

Comment: If you can share the remaining `HTML` it would help me a bit understanding what is behind it all.